# How to loop a command in python with a list as variable input?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

*This is my first post to the coding community, so I hope I get the right level of detail in my request for help!*

Background info:
I want to repeat (loop) command in a df using a variable that contains a list of options. While the series '*amenity_options*' contains a simple list of specific items (let's say only four amenities as the example below) the df is a large data frame with many other items. My goal is the run the operation below for each item in the '*amenity_option*' until the end of the list.

```
amenity_options = ['cafe','bar','cinema','casino'] # this is a series type with multiple options

df = df[df['amenity'] == amenity_options] # this is my attempt to select the the first value in the series (e.g. cafe) out of dataframe that contains such a column name.

df.to_excel('{}_amenity.xlsx, format('amenity') # wish to save the result (e.g. cafe_amenity) as a separate file.
```

Desired result:
I wish to loop step one and two for each and every item available in the list (e.g. cafe, bar, cinema...). So that I will have separate excel files in the end. Any thoughts?

Comment: `df[df['amenity'].isin(amenity_options)]`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, this would return a single output. The objective is to return separate files for each 'amenity', hence the loop function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Rakesh suggested is correct, you probably just need one more step.

```
df = df[df['amenity'].isin(amenity_options)]

for key, g in df.groupby('amenity'):
    g.to_excel('{}_amenity.xlsx'.format(key))
```

After you call `groupby()` of your df, you will get 4 groups so that you can directly loop on them.

The key is the group key, which are `cafe`, `bar` and etc. and the `g` is the sub-dataframe that specifically filtered by that key.

Comment: Thank you for the input Christopher. This works, but in reality, my problem is a bit more complicated. The df is actually a called API that accepts only one variable at a time. Hence my need to loop function. I formulated the problem here with a fixed df to simplify - your answer if helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a simple `for` loop:

```
for amenity in amenity_options:
    df[df['amenity'] == amenity].to_excel(f"{amenity}_amenity.xlsx")
```